# RANK of this category vs all categories, within USERELATIONSIP

Tags: powerbi, dax

In the image below, each bar represents the sum of a value for a main category (selected in the dashboard)

[image]

In the underlying table, this category sits alongside 500 categories, of which 4 are relevant sibling categories (which I can access via `USERELATIONSHIP`). The grey line is a representation of the average of the other four categories + the main one - it's a "me vs my peers" use case.

I require some kind of ranking to:

1. Rank the main category vs the other 4
2. As above but an overall ranking for all periods

In the below data example, we'd ignore the grey rows (via `USERELATIONSHIP`) and when loggged in as category 4, we'd see ourselves as `rank 1 of 5` for Jan, and `5 of 5` for Feb, and `rank 2 of 5` overall.

[image]

I have tried various `RANK`/`RANKX` syntax but get caught out due to needing only 5 categories (out of the 500) - I haven't found many (any?) examples of a `RANK`/`RANKX` with a `USERELATIONSHIP`.

Secondly I'm not sure how to add to the bar tooltip that it's the main category vs the others e.g. "rank 1 out of 5" ; plucking out the bolded information above, with context sensitivity for the bar (period).

In short:

- Ranked data needs filtering via USERELATIONASHIP
- Measure needs ranking for categories in the set & hovered month
- Measure also needs ranking for categories in the set + all displayed dates